# How to include config files when installing a python module via setuptools?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have written a module for use in a robotics application which provides access to robotic-specific characteristics, as well as python and c++ clients for using the data. The python client is bundled into a module using setuptools.

The (simplified) directory structure looks like this:

```
<root of git repo>
├── config
│   ├── global
│   │   ├── <files common to all robots>
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── robot1
│   │   ├── camera_calibrations
│   │   │   ├── cam1.yml
│   │   │   ├── cam2.yml
│   │   │   ├── cam3.yml
│   │   └── vehicle_params.yaml
│   ├── robot2
│   │   └── ...
│   └── ...
├── cpp
│   └── <c++ client>
├── Makefile
├── python
│   └── <namespace>
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── <module names>
│           ├── camera_calibrations.py
│           ├── ...
│           └── __init__.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

My setup.py looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from pip.req import parse_requirements
import shutil

# parse_requirements() returns generator of pip.req.InstallRequirement objects
REQUIREMENTS_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'requirements.txt')
dependencies = map(lambda ir: str(ir.req), parse_requirements(REQUIREMENTS_FILE, session='hack'))

CONFIG_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config')
MODULE_DIR = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'local', 'lib', 'python2.7', 'dist-packages', 'namespace', 'module_name')

def get_config_files():
    for root, _, files in os.walk(CONFIG_FOLDER):
        for filename in files:
            yield os.path.join(root, filename)

setup(
    name                 = "namespace.module_name",
    version              = "1.0.0",
    packages             = ['namespace.module_name'],
    package_dir          = {'': 'python'},
    #package_data         = {'': get_config_files()},
    install_requires     = dependencies,
    include_package_data = True,
    #data_files           = [(os.path.join(MODULE_DIR, 'config'), get_config_files())]
)

# Copy config files
## TODO: There's probably a better way to do this, but I've been working
## on it all morning soo....
CONFIG_DEST = os.path.join(MODULE_DIR, 'config')
if os.path.exists(CONFIG_DEST):
    shutil.rmtree(CONFIG_DEST)
shutil.copytree(CONFIG_FOLDER, CONFIG_DEST)
```

I want the python client to always be able to locate the configuration (yml) files relative to itself. So if you run it from source in the repo, it finds the copy in the local folder. If `pip install`ed and imported as a package, the install process should copy the config files alongside the `.py` files and then load this.

The hack that I settled on only works when the user installs as root, and so isn't a real solution. I also experimented with the `package_data` and `data_files` options in `setup`, but these didn't quite work out either (you can see what I tried, which I have commented out).

I also wrote this utility function inside the python client, which shows more of my hackery:

```
def get_config_dir():
    # pylint: disable=global-statement
    global CONFIG_DIR
    if CONFIG_DIR is None:
        # HACK HACK HACK
        search = [
            os.path.join(CUR_DIR, 'config'),
            os.path.join(CUR_DIR, '..', '..', '..', 'config'),
            os.path.join('..', '..', '..', 'config'),
        ]
        for path in search:
            if os.path.exists(path):
                CONFIG_DIR = os.path.abspath(path)
                return CONFIG_DIR
        raise CouldNotFindConfigFolderException("Could not find config folder")
    return CONFIG_DIR
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to how I can properly achieve this, I'd appreciate it.

One note is that its important that the config files are kept with the code and not elsewhere on the system, as the configs might change under version control, and it is crucial that changes are kept coupled to the code.

Comment: «The hack that I settled on only works when the user installs as root…» The real problem is not root access but wrong path in `MODULE_DIR` — you use absolur path which is certainly wrong as the module could be user-installed (`pip install --user`)l installed under different OS and Python veriosn, in a virtual environment. Don't rely on absolute paths.

Comment: In what ways `package_data` and `data_files` options in `setup.py` didn't quite work?

Comment: Do you ship a wheel or a source archive? For wheels, I could share a trick for data files outside of a package that should be installed inside that package. Otherwise, if you ship a source distribution (`zip`, `tar.gz`, `tar.bz2` etc), you either place the config files inside of a package directory and use `package_data`, or place the config files outside of the codebase and use `data_files`, but then you will need to distinguish between the installed case (some path relative to `sys.prefix`, depending on `data_files` configuration) and development case (path relative to the VCS root).